# Type 'CategoryModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'GenericModel<CategoryModel[]>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

When I send request to the server, the response will be given to me in this :

```
{ 
   data:array(6),
   message:"operation Success",
   isSuccess:true,
   statusCode:0
}
```

That's why I created a generic class :

```
export interface GenericModel<T> {
 data:T;
 isSuccess:boolean;
 statusCode:number;
 message:string;
 }
```

now i send a request to server for give me all `Category List` , i Create this Generic field:

`ListResponse:GenericModel<CategoryModel[]>;`

this CategoryModel :

```
export interface CategoryModel {
id:number;
name:string;
parentId:number;
}
```

And I use this function:

```
GetMainCat(){
this.categoryService.GetListItem(this.GetAllcatListUrl).subscribe(data=>{
  this.ListResponse=data
  console.log(this.listCatModel)
});
}
```

But in this line `this.ListResponse=data` it shows me error :

> Type 'CategoryModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'GenericModel': data, isSuccess, statusCode, messagets(2739)

Data has this format:

```
{ 
   data:array(6),
   message:"operation Success",
   isSuccess:true,
   statusCode:0
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say because we can't see how you set the `ListResponse` type. I'm guessing you need to set it to the correct type. Try to set it as `any` if it works you just used the type wrong

Edit: I see it now:

`ListResponse:CategoryModel[];`
This should fix it